# Why are my dialog boxes too small on some (but not all) Windows7 computers?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, dpi

I'm starting to test a Winforms (using VS2008) app on Windows 7, and am seeing a strange problem.

It ran fine on the first couple of Win7 installations, but on the next two, many of my dialogs are too small, clipping the content by about 30%.

The app was developed on WinXP, and have not seen this problem on **any** of the XP installations!

Just starting to investigate the problem - don't have any details on differences between the systems that work and those that don't yet.

**Edit**

According to Kate's comment to one of the answers, Win7 will sometimes change to a custom text size when a new monitor is installed. The machine with the problem has a big, widescreen monitor, and when we checked (Control Panel + Display + Custom Text Size) - sure enough - the custom text size was set to 125%. Setting it to 100% made the problem go away.

I was then able to replicate the problem on WinXP by setting the text size to 125%.

So the question now becomes - **how do you ensure a Winforms app is "custom text size independent"?**

**/Edit**

As suggested, here are some screen shots.  1st one is from a Windows 7 computer, 2nd one is from my WinXP development system.

[image: Windows 7]

[image: Windows XP]

Comment: Control Panel + Display, Set custom text size.  Use Form.AutoScaleMode.

Comment: It looks like your Win7 machine has both a Theme (the title bar is not Aero) and font enlarging. You need to do what Hans says.

Comment: What is the recommended setting for AutoScaleMode?  Also, can AutoSizeMode properties play a role here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both screen DPI and Themes can change the size of controls, that is not the problem here because in your screen shots the window chrome and non-text control sizes are unchanged. The problem is you are not taking custom font sizes into account.

If you wanted to move controls around to fix them into a fixed form size you would have to perform calculations using the `Control.AutoScaleDimensions` property of your controls. That is a lot of work, don't do that.

Instead, lay out your controls using absolute coordinates and enlarge your form to contain the results. Set your forms' `AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "lay out your controls using absolute coordinates and enlarge your form to contain the results".  Are these things I need to do programmatic-ally?  If so, how?  Or are you saying this happens as a result of simply setting AutoScaleMode?  Clarification would be much appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio design mode, just drag the controls so they look right in the editor. The design file will contain absolute coordinates (pixels) for sizes. If you set `AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font` then the container will resize itself according to the runtime font magnification without you having to do anything. Controls already do this; notice how the GroupBoxes and dropdown menus resize themselves to contain the larger text?

Comment: I'm having a slightly different issue -- in most cases my forms are too big in 125% and 150% -- in others, the layout is all crazy (radio buttons end up on top of each other, etc) -- and worse yet, it appears AutoScaleMode is already set to Font... -- I've tried DPI, Font, and Inherit -- none seem to have any effect.  I'm using docked controls, but there just seems to be wide gaps between them in 125% -- any other thoughts?

Comment: (Edit to my above [it's been 5 minutes], sorry) -- "None" also seems to have no effect.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83; there are other things that can change layout; post a question with screen shots.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when a Win 7 user adjusted the default font size in "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display"

When you have forms set to "Fixed Dialog" set the following properties on your form: .AutoScaleMode=Font .AutoSize=True .AutoSizeMode=GrowOnly so windows can resize your form based on the sizes of the child elements.

[image: AutoScaleMode=Font AutoSize=True AutoSizeMode=GrowOnly]

Answer (score 2):

Display size, resolution, DPI, large fonts, small fonts are some possible causes.

Comment: Themes, localizations, and screen effects are additional possibilities but, yeah, font enlarging would be my guess as well. A screen shot would help us narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: What is the resolution on the machines where this happens and the ones where it doesn't? Windows 7 sets your DPI for you if you have a really big screen. You need to make your app DPI aware.

Comment: @Kate - looks you've identified the root cause.  The machine with the problem has a big, widescreen monitor, and when we checked, sure enough, the custom text size was set to 125%.  Setting it to 100% made the problem go away.

Comment: @Tom depending on your user base, telling them how to get it back to 100% may suffice, but I would see it as a stopgap until you can make code changes that enable the app to look great at any DPI.

Comment: @Kate - I've updated the question.  Any tips on making my app DPI aware? Write it as an answer, instead of a comment, if you want the votes...