# Large Display Text Moving Controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a .Net Windows application. All the controls arrange fine, but when the user specifies their Windows display text to be larger than the Windows 7 default of 'Smaller', the controls get moved around on the form and makes it unusable.

Is there a way to lock down those controls no matter what the display text setting is at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *solution* to your problem is to use [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) as this is resolution independent.

Your *workaround* to the problem is to test your app in various different configurations of text size and screen resolution and put enough space around everything in *standard* size so that it still fits when the user resizes.

Comment: Winforms are perfectly capable of working in multiple resolutions without having to put space around everything.

Comment: @Dour - Screen resolutions Yes - Text Sizes No

Comment: That makes sense. I'll just have to keep that in mind for future apps. It was just really interesting when it happened when all the controls ended up in all weird places.

Comment: Text sizes Yes, investigate `AutoScaleMode.Font`

Answer (score 0):

There are many things other than font sizes that can move your controls around. If something is moving your controls around, it is because it is necessary to read or display the text, "locking down" the controls will not help.

You have to write your app so it takes control sizes into account. There is another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983569) that explains this.