# .NET Custom Control: Prevent font size change/ inherit font scale/size from parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created some controls in C#, and am successfully using them. However, on user PC's with custom set (font) DPI to let's say 125 % or even 150 % -- My controls inherit the new scale, and do not display correctly.

I would like to know how to disable my control from inheriting this scale.

Comment: C# is just a language. There are controls in winforms, wpf, asp, silverlight, etc. You could possibly add more special tags. Also, it will be helpful to know at least base class of your controls.

Comment: DPI scaling is quite important, you can't just turn it off.  Fix the "do not display correctly" problem, whatever it might be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my dialog boxes too small on some (but not all) Windows7 computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983569/why-are-my-dialog-boxes-too-small-on-some-but-not-all-windows7-computers)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not the answer you would be looking for. But consider why people have their system set the way it is. it may be a vision problem or just their perference. Yes, handling the scaling diplay can be a pain, but that is better then a user disregarding your product because they can't read/use it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're building your own application, you can set the AutoScaleMode property of a Form to "None" to disable the automatic resizing of the Form's font based on the system DPI setting.

If you're simply building a control that others will integrate into their own forms, you'll want to override the Font property of the control and force it to your pre-determined hardcoded value.

Also note that, as others have said, you *don't want to do this* -- the user has adjusted their system DPI for a reason, and overriding their choice is likely only going to make your control unusable to them.  If the problem is merely that your control isn't scaling correctly when the system DPI is changed, make use of Winform's AutoSize capabilities and use layout panels that will automatically adjust as the size of things change, such as TableLayoutPanel (with AutoSize set appropriately on rows and columns) or FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: +1 for the actual solution to the question, thank you. In my situation I have to make a UserControl that is imported in another software package that already includes a whole bunch of UserControls that have this turned off. If I don't turn it off, my UserControl will be the only one inheriting these settings. In addition, the default settings within that software package are completely different from the fixed settings of all the other UserControls. So in my situation the look and feel inheritance feature is broken by the existing UserControls and I have to deal with it.